# SOQL query to get files names related to account

Tags: soql, query, attachment, sosl, parent-to-child

I want to get the names of all related files in the Account object. Below is my query:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Id from Attachments) FROM Account WHERE Id= '0014K00000C6b7pQAB'
```

When I run the query, it does not display any results. How can I query the related files?

Comment: SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '[RECORD ID]'. Then you can do SOQL on ContentDocument - Select Id ,Title from ContentDocument Where ID In :[CONTENTDOCUMENTLIST]

Comment: I've linked a possibly relevant answer, and Anudeep has actually stated that you might be querying the wrong object. Can you check to see if (a) you're debugging correctly and (b) that you're querying the correct file storage object? If we need to reopen this question, I'd be happy to do so.